# Getting stuck at receiving firebase notification to iOS real device but got on android device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am stuck with this problem from last week i have tried and tested all possible link from stack overflow and Github but couldn't find any solution for that so the problem is i am using flutter technology as my code base and implemented firebase push notification with use of firebase_messaging package, i am getting notification on Android device via firebase but not receiving and notification on iOS(real) device. here is my code below

1. I have placed GoogleService-Info.plist directly under the runner folder
2. I have also attached APNs certificate and enable push notification in capabilities and in background mode also enabled background fetch and remote notification

here is my AppDelegate file code

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

here is my info plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>DropZone</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>camera</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>photos</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

here is my push notification service file

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm;

  PushNotificationService(this._fcm);

  Future initialise() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
    }

    _fcm.subscribeToTopic("mytargettopic");
  }
}
```